# Calendar, SkyDrive, Photos, Messaging crash on launch

Tags: windows-8, crash, modern-ui

These 4 apps - Calendar, SkyDrive, Photos and Messaging crash on launching them almost always. I saw the Applications log and it redirected me to the TWinUI/Operational Log. In that log, it says Access Denied. What do I do? Please give me a solution which doesn't need me to refresh. Thanks

This problem has started around 1-2 weeks back.

```
sfc /scannow
```

says no resource integrity violations found

Comment: Please post the important parts from the error log.

Comment: It just says Access Denied. Anyways a reinstall of my AV (KIS 13) has solved the issue. I think it was blocking the apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with my AV. Reinstalled it and cleaned the registry and everything is fine now